# Use Android Support Annotations like @StringRes, @LayoutRes, @DrawableRes for arrays of integers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I was trying to search for any samples or any documentation about using recently introduced annotations in Android Support Library for **arrays**. Particularly, I want to annotate array of integers with [Resource Type Annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations#TOC-Resource-Type-Annotations), like `@StringRes`, `@DrawableRes`, `@ColorRes`, etc.

I've tried to use these annotations in Android Studio 1.3, version details:

```
Android Studio 1.3
Build #AI-141.2117773, built on July 28, 2015
JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716 x86_64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Apple Inc.
```

Support library declaration: `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'`

Sample source code:

```
public void test(@NonNull Context context) {
    method(context, new int[]{1}); // no warn/error here
}

public void method(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int[] ids) {
    context.getString(ids[0]); // no warn/error here
}
```

Unfortunately, this code produces no errors, no warnings, maybe because Resource Type Annotations of current version aren't designed to be used in conjunction with arrays, but I'm not sure.

My questions - **is there a way to use Resource Type Annotations for int arrays**?

**Update**:

I've added the case with varargs, they seem like broken too, but slightly in a different way:

```
public void test(@NonNull Context context) {
    method(context, 1, 2, 3); // there is warn only for 2nd argument, saying it must be Drawable type. But no warns to 3rd and 4th params.
}

public void method(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int... ids) {
    context.getString(ids[0]); // no warn/error here
}
```

Comment: Varargs seems to work ok if it's any help - i.e _"@StringRes int... ids"_ .

Comment: @harism Actually, it doesn't work for varargs either. I've just updated my question to add case with varargs.